# Webpack: export default class is not defined on index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Webpack.

I have a class that I'm exporting and trying to instantiate on my index.html.
(This is an updated version of the original thread)

```
"use strict";

import {TimelineModule} from "./modules/timeline.module.js";
import {NavigationModule} from './modules/navigation.module.js';
import {FiltersModule} from "./modules/filters.module.js";
import VGLogger from "./modules/logger.module.js";
import {DataSourcesModule} from "./modules/data-sources.module.js";
import {EventsModule} from "./modules/events.module.js";


export default class extends EventsModule {
    constructor(params = null) {
        super();
        this.gridTimeline = null;
        this.gridNavigation = null;
        this.gridFilters = null;
        this.dataSources = new DataSourcesModule();
        this.uniqueID = (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);

        this.settings.gridSettings = {
            ...this.settings.gridSettings,
            ...params
        };

        VGLogger.log(`New VanillaGrid Instance Created!`, `log`);
    }

    create(gridDOMIdentifier) {
        this.#setWrapper(gridDOMIdentifier);
        this.#renderNavigation();
        this.#renderFilters();
        this.#renderTimeline();
        this.initEvents();
    }

    #renderTimeline() {
        this.gridTimeline = new TimelineModule(this.gridWrapper);
    }

    #renderNavigation() {
        this.gridNavigation = new NavigationModule(this.gridWrapper, this.getSettingValue('navigation'));
    }

    #renderFilters() {
        this.gridFilters = new FiltersModule(this.gridWrapper);
    }

    #setWrapper(wrapper) {
        this.gridWrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper);
        const wrapperClass = this.getSettingValue('wrapperClass');
        this.gridWrapper.classList.add(`${wrapperClass}`);
        this.gridWrapper.classList.add(`vg-${this.uniqueID}`);
    }
}
```

My library.js file looks like:

```
const VanillaGrid = require('./index.js').default;
module.exports = VanillaGrid;
// Based on this post -> https://www.seancdavis.com/blog/export-es6-class-globally-webpack/
```

My config file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        library: "VanillaGrid",
        libraryTarget: "var"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    entry: {
        main: ['./src/library.js'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'sample/index.html'
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: [
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                            '@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties',
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

And .babelrc:

```
{
"sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Samples</title>
  <script defer src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thing is that VanillaGrid is undefined on my index.html and can't figure out why.
Placed some breakpoints on Webpack's flow, and the class is accessible from within Webpack, but I need to access to it as a global constructor.

---

UPDATE:
So, been analyzing the resuting bundle, and in its final lines have this:

```
// startup
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    // This entry module is referenced by other modules so it can't be inlined
/******/    __webpack_require__("./src/library.js");
/******/    var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__("./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:9000");
/******/    VanillaGrid = __webpack_exports__;
```

It is assigning this other file that seems to be part of Webpack's dev server to my plugin's global variable.
This seems to be webpack-dev-server related.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your HTML file doesn't appear to load a Webpack bundle?

Comment: My bad, copied the src version of the file. Updated it to how it actually is once webpack processed it

Comment: There may be other issues, but at a minimum `defer` there means that `main.js` won't run until after `new SomeClass()`.

Comment: You may also need to set your Library's name so that you then do `new LibName()` since it's the library you are importing, and the export of that just happens to be a constructor that was originally named `SomeClass`.

Comment: Already did that but it's not working out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hard to say, sorry. I'd recommend looking at the output JS file to see what Webpack outputs with those flags to figure out why it's not working for you, since that should definitely get things going in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you mixing `import` and `require`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this simplified version of your code and it worked perfectly:

```
"use strict";

export default class {
    constructor(params = null) {
        this.gridTimeline = null;
        this.gridNavigation = null;
        this.gridFilters = null;
        this.uniqueID = (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    create(gridDOMIdentifier) {
        this.#setWrapper(gridDOMIdentifier);
        this.#renderNavigation();
        this.#renderFilters();
        this.#renderTimeline();
        this.initEvents();
    }

    #renderTimeline() {

    }

    #renderNavigation() {

    }

    #renderFilters() {

    }

    #setWrapper(wrapper) {

    }
}
```

The package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.13.0",
  "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
  "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
  "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
  "webpack": "^5.35.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
}
```

Here is the output with some test code:

```js
// Beginning of webpack output

var VanillaGrid;
(() => {
  var t = {
    352: (t, e, n) => {
      "use strict";
      function i(t, e) {
        for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
          var i = e[n];
          i.enumerable = i.enumerable || !1,
          i.configurable = !0,
          "value" in i && (i.writable = !0),
          Object.defineProperty(t, i.key, i)
        }
      }
      function r(t, e, n) {
        if (!e.has(t))
          throw new TypeError("attempted to get private field on non-instance");
        return n
      }
      n.d(e, {
        Z: () => u
      });
      var a = new WeakSet,
      o = new WeakSet,
      s = new WeakSet,
      l = new WeakSet,
      u = function () {
        function t() {
          (function (t, e) {
            if (!(t instanceof e))
              throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
          })(this, t),
          l.add(this),
          s.add(this),
          o.add(this),
          a.add(this),
          this.gridTimeline = null,
          this.gridNavigation = null,
          this.gridFilters = null,
          this.uniqueID = (65536 * (1 + Math.random()) | 0).toString(16).substring(1)
        }
        var e,
        n;
        return e = t,
        (n = [{
              key: "create",
              value: function (t) {
                r(this, l, d).call(this, t),
                r(this, o, h).call(this),
                r(this, s, f).call(this),
                r(this, a, c).call(this),
                this.initEvents()
              }
            }
          ]) && i(e.prototype, n),
        t
      }
      ();
      function c() {}
      function h() {}
      function f() {}
      function d(t) {}
    },
    509: (t, e, n) => {
      var i = n(352).Z;
      t.exports = i
    }
  },
  e = {};
  function n(i) {
    var r = e[i];
    if (void 0 !== r)
      return r.exports;
    var a = e[i] = {
      exports: {}
    };
    return t[i](a, a.exports, n),
    a.exports
  }
  n.d = (t, e) => {
    for (var i in e)
      n.o(e, i) && !n.o(t, i) && Object.defineProperty(t, i, {
        enumerable: !0,
        get: e[i]
      })
  },
  n.o = (t, e) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, e);
  var i = n(509);
  VanillaGrid = i
})();

// End of webpack output

// Beginning of the test code

const grid = new VanillaGrid;

console.log(grid.uniqueID);
```

If your problem is the class not being available immediately in a synchronous `script` tag, try adding `scriptLoading: "blocking"` in the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` configuration in order to remove the `defer` attribute from the generated `script` tag.

If that doesn't answer your question, you should add details on the `bundle.js` output and on how you try to use the generated code.

Comment: It seems to be dev server related. Checked the bundle, and the resut assigns the library correctly to VanillaGrid global variable. But when I run webpack dev server, is when this happens.

Comment: So when you double click on the html file to open it as `file:///` it works?

Comment: If I run index.html with Webstorm's run function, it works

Comment: It works for me with this config: `devServer: { contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), compress: true, port: 9000 }`

Comment: @Pablo I just saw you awarded me the bounty. I'm curious did you eventually find out what was wrong?